# Drawing a set partition

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to reproduce this diagram

[image]

What I tried :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);

    \foreach \i in {1,...,5}
        \draw (0,0) -- ({360/5*\i}:3cm);

    \foreach \i/\label in {1/A_1, 2/A_2, 3/A_3, 4/A_4, 5/A_5}
        \node at ({360/5*(\i-0.5)}:2.5cm) {\(\label\)};

    \node at (-2.5cm,2.5cm) {$\Omega$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result

[image]

Comment: Are the curves specific or do you just need to approximate the shape?

Comment: Approximating the shape is okay yes

Comment: @Dots You chould learn to draw Bézier curves with `TikZ`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse[x radius=3cm, y radius=2cm];
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} \path ({360/5*\i}:3cm and 2cm) coordinate (A\i);
\path (-2.5,0) node {$\mathrm{A}_1$};
\path (130:0.6*3cm and 0.6*2cm) node {$\mathrm{A}_2$};
\path (280:0.1*3cm and 0.1*2cm) node {$\mathrm{A}_3$};
\path (30:0.7*3cm and 0.7*2cm) node {$\mathrm{A}_4$};
\path (-30:0.7*3cm and 0.7*2cm) node {$\mathrm{A}_5$};
\draw[name path=curve]
    (A4)
    .. controls +(110:0.5) and +(-5:0.5) ..
    (A1)
    .. controls +(175:0.5) and +(-60:0.5) ..
    (A3)
    .. controls +(120:0.5) and +(-30:1.5) ..
    (A2);
\path[name path=line] (0,0) -- (3,0);
\path[name intersections={of=curve and line, by=Z}];
\draw (Z) -- (3,0);
\path (160:3cm and 2cm) coordinate (A);
\path (A) ++(160:1cm) node[circle, draw] (omega) {$\Omega$};
\draw (omega) -- (A);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun. Here is a way do it.

```
\documentclass[border=0.618cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1.5pt]
%The empty ellipse node with minimum width 6cm and minimum height 4cm
\node [ellipse,draw,minimum width=6cm, minimum height=4cm] (ep) at (0,0) {};

%Draw the Bézier curve and the horizontal line to make segments inside the ellipse
\draw ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]ep.145)
.. controls ++(1.2,-1) and ++(-0.2,0.2)
.. ([shift={(0.5\pgflinewidth,0.5\pgflinewidth)}]ep.215)
.. controls ++(0.2,-0.2) and ++ (-0.3,0.2) 
.. ([shift={(-0.5\pgflinewidth,-0.5\pgflinewidth)}]ep.60) 
.. controls ++(0.3,-0.2) and ++(0,0) 
.. node (mp) [pos=0.485] {}  ([yshift=0.5\pgflinewidth]ep.-65);
\draw (mp.center) -- ([xshift=-0.5\pgflinewidth]ep.east);

%Draw label omega outside the ellipse
\node (lb) [draw,circle] at ([shift={(-0.5,0.5)}]ep.155) {$\Omega$};
\draw (ep.155) -- (lb);

%Draw the labels for each segment
\node at ([xshift=0.75cm]ep.west) {$A_1$};
\node at ([shift={(-0.75cm,1cm)}]ep.center) {$A_2$};
\node at ([shift={(0.1cm,-0.7cm)}]ep.center) {$A_3$};
\node at ([shift={(1.95cm,0.75cm)}]ep.center) {$A_4$};
\node at ([shift={(1.95cm,-0.75cm)}]ep.center) {$A_5$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With the `decorations.markings` library, I place nodes on the ellipse which are numbered `(mark-1)` to `(mark-5)`, I add the node `(mi)`.
With bezier curves I trace the curves. And with the `barycentric coordinates`, I place the labels `A_1` etc.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {decorations.markings,calc,positioning}


\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{cmark/.style={decoration={
markings,mark=at position #1 with {\coordinate[name={mark-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}];}},postaction={decorate}},
mimark/.style={decoration={
markings,mark=at position .5 with {\coordinate[name=mi];}},postaction={decorate}}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [cmark/.list={0,.2,.4,.45,.6,.8}](0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
\draw (mark-3)to[controls=+(-40:1.5) and +(120:.5)]
        (mark-5)to[controls=+(-30:.5) and +(170:1)]
        (mark-2);
\draw[mimark]   (mark-2)to [controls=+(-10:.5) and +(110:.5)](mark-6);
\draw(mark-1)--(mi);
\node at (barycentric cs:mark-3=1,mark-5=1) {$A_1$};
\node at (barycentric cs:mark-3=1,mark-5=1 ,mark-2=1) {$A_2$};
\node at (barycentric cs:mark-6=1,mark-5=1 ,mark-2=1) {$A_3$};
\node at (barycentric cs:mi=1,mark-1=1 ,mark-2=1) {$A_4$};
\node at (barycentric cs:mi=1,mark-1=1 ,mark-6=1) {$A_5$};
\node[above left=2mm and 4mm of mark-4,draw,circle,inner sep=1pt]{$\Omega$} edge (mark-4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]